# Plotting 2 plots with different size in the same figure using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to demonstrate the aliasing effect on a sine wave. I have a signal y(x) to be plotted against x with len(x)=180 and another signal y1(x1) to be plotted against x1 with len(x1)= 300.

I have them plotted in different subplots. However, they are the same signal represented by different numbers of points. And wish to overlay those signals in the same subplot. Is that possible?

(i am using python 2.7 with matplotlib)

couldn't find this anywhere.

Comment: `plot(x, y, x1, y1)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just call `plot` twice.  Alternately, you can can combine the `plot` calls as @tcaswell pointed out.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1, x2 = [np.linspace(0, 10, num) for num in [10, 100]]
y1 = np.cos(x1)
y2 = np.sin(x2)

plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know why I got stuck with this as this is something so obvious.... Sometimes we can't see what is right in front of us. Thank you for clarifying this for me! =)